# xterm: Can't execvp: No file or directory

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, xterm

I am writing a C program in linux.

I have created a process and forking it to create a child. I want to run another program in this child so I am using `execlp`. But, this program must run in an independent window.

```
if ( (execlp("xterm","xterm","-e","./Child1", "127.0.0.1", (char *) 0)) < 0)  {
  printf("Failed to Start the Echo Client. Exiting application.");
  return 1;
}
```

`Child1.c` is a simple program which is in the same directory as my current file.

On execution the code runs fine with the xterm window coming up but I get an error   `"xterm: Can't execvp: No file or directory"`

Can you please suggest me a resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system might not have an `xterm` installed (or the user has a wrong `PATH`). You could test the existence of `/usr/bin/xterm` (with e.g. the `access` syscall), or use something else. For example, many Debian or Ubuntu distributions have a `x-terminal-emulator` (which is usually a symlink to some precise program) which you could use instead of `xterm`.

If `xterm` fires up, then your program `./Child1` does not exist, you should test its existence (with `access`) before. If you only have a source code `./Child1.c` you should have compiled it before (perhaps by running a `system("gcc -Wall Child1.c -o Child1")` before and testing that it has compiled successfully, i.e. test that `system` returns 0 and that the `Child1` file exists and is executable).

You should take time to read the [xterm(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm) man page.

Comment: my sytem has an xterm because when I simply type xterm in the ubuntu command line I see a new window.

Comment: Can you tell me what u mean by wrong PATH? Am I supposed to set the path somewhere? Pardon my comments; I am new to linux programming

Comment: If you do run `xterm -e ./Child1` on the command line, what is happenning? If you just run `./Child1` what is happenning? And `PATH` is explained in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: Hi Nothing is happening when I type xterm -e ./Child1. But when I do xterm ./Child1, I get an error saying that "No Absolute Path found for shell" and a new window opens up.

Comment: I wasnt creating the output object file Child1 because of which this error came up. Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: `Child1` is not an object file, but should be some executable binary ELF file.